# rails select_tag selected no working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm not sure what I am doing wrong but my `select_tag :selected` is not working. Check the code below:

```
<%= select_tag :supplier, options_from_collection_for_select(SupplierItem.select("DISTINCT(SUPPLIER)").group("SUPPLIER"), "SUPPLIER", "SUPPLIER"), { :selected => params[:supplier], prompt: "Select a Category"} %>
```

Comment: I you want to get help you need to provide more information. How are is you model look like. Is there are any relationship in you model/models?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had the `:selected => params[:supplier]` in the wrong place. Working code below:

```
<%= select_tag :supplier, options_from_collection_for_select(SupplierItem.select("DISTINCT(SUPPLIER)").group("SUPPLIER"), "SUPPLIER", "SUPPLIER" ,:selected => params[:supplier]), {prompt: "Select a Category"}  %>
```

Answer (score 0):

As per [the docs](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormTagHelper.html#method-i-select_tag), `select_tag` doesn't accept a `:selected` option because the `<option>` tags are all rendered by `options_from_collection_for_select` already by the time the `select_tag` is called.

So instead, as per [the docs](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormOptionsHelper.html#method-i-options_from_collection_for_select), `options_from_collection_for_select` takes, as it's optional fourth parameter, the selected value.